# Non Muslim believes in karma and nature, not Allah

Tags: non-muslim

Non Muslim person said he believes this world was created by Nature, and that things that happen in his life is due to karma. He doesn't seem to believe in Allah.

I tell him this Nature was created by Allah.

Then he asks so Who created Allah?

How can I answer to him? I know to answer him but our answer should be thinkable. So that's why.

Comment: Just a note: People are of two types: one who isn’t sincerely asking you a question, no amount of logic would convince him. Some atheist just don’t care. Yet need to feel the void of not having a reason to not believe. The other type are people who sincerely ask questions and are convinced upon the the simplest hints. Once you know these two types identifying the person becomes easy and you won’t let them waste your time for silly questions. I understand you may judge incorrectly, but usually after some discussion it becomes obvious.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a reasonably answerable question it attracts subjective answers. Beside this site is not meant as a peer support nor to preach the truth.

Answer (score 1):

**The first thing** is that you need to study **Aqidah** before trying to involve yourself in such questions or answering any non-Muslim/atheists questions.

**Second**, they will have as many questions more than you imagine, and these questions are asked in a wrong way, because their problem is not with Who created ALLAH or How the world existed..etc, their problem is with the **ISLAM** itself, and most of their questions are logically false.

**Third**, let him think what he think if he insists, we are now living in age of **Fitna** **(temptation)**, and you are not a man of science or knowledgeable enough (nor me also), keep developing yourself and learn more about Islam, Worship ALLAH more by knowing and understanding his names, but choose your resource carefully, search a lot before judging something, and once more **STUDY ISLAM MORE**

**Forth:** If he is telling you that nature created everything around us, then you ask what is Nature to you ? 
**is it:**

1. The things around us, sea, mountains, skies, planets,...etc ?
2. The laws that govern the movement of everything around us ?
3. Some super-natural force beyond the this world and beyond our perception ?

**In case 1**: 
this would be non-sense, because how is that the sky creates itself, or a sand creates itself? a normal human brain will refuse such thing. In addition, all nature things such as sky, land, stars, suns,..etc doesn't have brain, or eyes, or ears, so a low rank creature cannot create something more intelligent and aware-able more than it. What created something so precise as the planets movement in the sky without anyone crashing into the other, cannot be created by something that doesn't think.

**In case** **2**: 
here they are not answering the question and saying who created the universe, they simply stating how the universe works, not who created these laws that move and organize the universe, and make everything work the way it is.

**In case** **3**:
If he say that there is a force that created the world that is super-natural, and that this force is very wise and powerful, and capable, and elegant and unique. We say it is correct, you call it super-unknown-force, and we call him "ALLAH". If he then say that he doesn't agree, then his problem is with ISLAM and ALLAH as a source of this universe.

In any case, this answer is for you before him, try not to go into deep conversations with such topic, until you become aware, and you should know that there are ways to prove the existence of ALLAH for Muslims and another ways for non-Muslims ... this is because Muslims already believe, but they might have a weak moment of suspect, so the way you speak with Muslim is different than non-Muslim.

May Allah always guide us to the straight path that will lead into Heaven.

Answer (score 0):

As'salaam `| The source of peace`
to you `| u'Alykum`.

God says in Chapter 87, `| translating into English`

> > `87:9` So remind, perhaps the reminder will help.
> >     `87:10` He who is concerned will remember.
> >     `87:11` And he who is wicked will avoid it.

Sounds like the person you are speaking with is uncomfortable with anything outside the "cause" and "effect" relationship.

In other words, if everything must have a cause, then so too must "God" so-called. It's an age old argument that Aristotle tried to respond to with something called the `Un-moved mover` argument.

However, cause and effect is a temporal relationship.

But, God claims in `112:2` that *Allah'hu'ṣamad*. [Translators][] also seem to have a difficult time with that term, however one way of saying it `| in English` is that God is absolute, indivisible, eternal. Timeless.

God simply is, `| in other words`. God is a being, from which matter such as "nature" emerges.

---

Re

> Non Mulsim person said he believes this world was created by Nature

- Yep, that's not an uncommon belief ⤵
- and `| Everyone is entitled to their beliefs`
- God says in `2:256` ⤵

`| translating into [English][``]`

> > There is no compulsion in the system; the proper way has been clarified from the wrong way. Whoever rejects evil, and believes in God, indeed he has taken grasp of the strongest hold that will never break. God is Hearer, Knower.

- You can *try* and respond like Abraham did in `2:258`, however be prepared to move on ⤵
- If this person is willing to accept that 'nature' has always existed, then why not God?

> the things happened his life is karma

- Cause and effect ⤵
- Sure `| No problem with that`
- In `2:25` God also tells us that *the things we do* will have an effect ⤵
- *Very positive effects* **if you also believe** (*āmanū waʿamilū l-ṣāliḥāt*)

> he doesn't believe Allah

- Insha'allah (iff God wills)

---

> ... but Our answer should be thinkable ...

- This my friend is not easy
- There's no "reason" and "logic" based answer that *everyone* will agree to in 2019 for example `| just to be clear, unless God wills`
- God has informed us of this in `2:6`

Indeed, how can you expect someone who is 100% totally committed to cause and effect as the explanation to everything be okay with a stick turning into a snake as it did for Moses? See `26:32`.

[Resources]

- []: https://www.islamawakened.com/quran/2/256
- []: https://www.islamawakened.com/quran/112/2

Answer (score 0):

> لَكُمْ دِينُكُمْ وَلِيَ دِينِ

[109:6](https://legacy.quran.com/109/6)

There is really no need for you to convince him of your religion .Islam is not seen in words ,it manifests in action.Its the soul of Islam that is a direct expression of its message ,like the taste of sugar, inexplicable unless you taste it ,the sahaba understood Islam from the behavior of Muhammad ,he was an expression of Islam, the hadith is not merely instruction ,you can see in it the soul of Muhammad, his wisdom ,his humility.Its that experiential message that lead to the unification of the Middle-East.You can become Muslim because of a poor illiterate man without the need of logic to understand it.

If you really believe in Allah ,its because you see the subjective ,you see the beauty in nature ,your belief is simply natural ,that other person also has his own believes in karma .You can just tell him that religion is subjective ,it is a faith in the subjective a faith in good human qualities like mercy ,peace ,compassion and equality, all cannot be seen physically, all cannot be proven scientifically...however so natural.. so beautiful .

If you can become an expression of Islam, you can unit Muslims and non Muslims alike without a single word.

Bless you brother :) .